# YouTube iframe API events not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, youtube, embed

I have been having issues with [YouTube](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YouTube)'s iframe API in Firefox! I am using [Google's very own code](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Getting_Started) and the callbacks in the events object are never called!

I'm on Windows 64 bit with Firefox 21 and my [Flash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Flash) is also updated to its latest version. I also have removed the [HTTPS Everywhere](https://www.eff.org/https-everywhere) extension which caused problems.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a problem at YouTube's end at the moment. `onStateChange` isn't fired anymore for at least the last 60 minutes.

Update, on the Google Data APIs home at [Google Code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Code): *[Issue 4706. iframe API: onStateChange not firing](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=4706)*